# Mode après « que » remplaçant une autre conjonction

Tags: verbes, conjonctions, subjonctif, mode-grammatical

Je voudrais savoir s'il existe quelques particularités dans l'usage des temps et des modes des verbes après ***que*** qui remplace une autre conjonction (*si*, *quand*, *parce que*, etc.).

J'ai déjà trouvé qu'il y a l'exception pour si : on utilise le subjonctif (*Si je pars sans parapluie et qu'il pleuve …*), donc y a-t-il d'autres exceptions, ou existe-il quelque règle de concordance dans ce cas-là?

Comment: Où peut-on trouver qu'il faut écrire « Si je pars sans parapluie et qu'il pleuve »  plutôt que « Si je pars sans parapluie et qu'il pleut » ?

Comment: C'est une "formule". On peut trouver dans le Grevisse des exemples: Comme si la Mère de Dieu résistait et qu’il fallût la vaincre à force de prières et d’objurgations ( Barrès, Colline insp., p. 95).  —  Comme s’il était arrivé jusqu’au bord même d’un abîme et qu’il le trouvât à ses pieds (Jaloux, Le reste est silence, ix).   —  Comme si vous bandiez un arc et que soudain vous ayez lâché sa corde (Butor, Modification, p. 223). Comme j'ai compris, l'utilisation du subjonctif n'est pas obligatoire, mais je m'intéresse à d'autres exceptions, parce que le français n'est pas ma langue maternelle.

Comment: Ces exemples ne sont pas très convaincants pour justifier la phrase de la question initiale qui me paraît toujours incorrecte jusqu'à preuve du contraire. Il aurait fallu écrire par exemple « Comme si je partais sans parapluie et qu'il pleuve ».

Comment: Dans ce cas-là vous pouvez regarder 'Remarque' sur la page 283 de 'Nouvelle grammaire du français. Cours de la civilsation française de la Sorbonne', Y. Delatour, Hachette: - Si votre CV nous intéresse et que vous soyez disponible, nous vous enverrons une lettre d'embauche.

Comment: D'accord, on a ici la même structure et un subjonctif, j'ai aussi trouvé « S’il réussit le bac et qu’il obtienne une mention, il intègrera une classe préparatoire » ( http://ecrivains-publics.fr/Le-point-du-mardi-Passe-de-mode-le ). je m'incline...

Comment: « S’il réussit le bac et qu’il obtienne une mention » et « Si votre CV nous intéresse et que vous soyez disponible » ne sonnent vraiment pas bien pour moi. Si c'est grammaticalement correct, ce n'est clairement pas utilisé couramment. Utiliser la forme présente est préférable à mon avis : « S’il réussit le bac et qu’il **obtient** une mention ».

Comment: Pour reprendre la discussion sur la question elle-même, il est difficile de répondre dans la mesure où la plupart des francophones rejettent la prémisse pour *si* au présent malgré les justifications fournies.

Answer (score 1):

À considérer les commentaires sur la question posée et les illustrations littéraires érudites données, je proposerais volontiers l'explication suivante :
Les deux variantes « Si...+ indicatif et que + **indicatif** » et « Si...+ indicatif et que + **subjonctif** » se différencient par l'accent porté ou non sur la conditionnalité du second élément par rapport au premier.

Je précise : dans le premier cas, les deux propositions (partir sans parapluie) et (il pleut) sont mises sur le même plan. Dans la seconde, on introduit une subtile subordination : « Si je pars sans parapluie et **que dans ce cas** il pleuve... ». Le second élément suppose la réalisation du premier (voir l'exemple avec le bac et la mention), ce qui amène l'usage du subjonctif.

C'est finaud, rare, mais superbe stylistiquement...

Answer (score 0):

On peut considérer les deux parties de manière un peu distincte:

- la première: si je sors, ou si je sortais

**A le que de la deuxième est synonyme de s'il arrive que**

- la deuxième est équivalente à : s'il arrive (ou s'il arrivait) qu'il pleuve => subjonctif

**B le que de la deuxième est une sorte de conjonction : synonyme de et si**

- la deuxième est équivalente à : s'il pleut => indicatif

Le cas A  suppose que le phénomène est lié à la sortie.

le cas B est une conjoncton plus simple.

Explication proche de celle de Chambaron.

Et après il faut aussi avoir des temps compatibles.

**Autres cas**

avant que => subjonctif: avant qu'il ne vienne

après que => indicatif ou subjonctif si la proposition est sûre ou incertaine

afin que => plutôt subjonctif

Il y en a certainement bien d'autres ...